Examples of finitary problems/theorems of high logical complexity?
Generally, number theoretic conjectures which are well-known and easy to explain are either obviously $\Pi^0_1$ or $\Pi^0_2$, which is to say, their truth can be decided by a single membership query to some $\Pi^0_{1/2}$ set.
For example the Goldbach conjecture and Fermat last theorem are "obviously" $\Pi^0_1$, and the ordinary Riemann hypothesis less obviously so, and the (in)famous Collatz conjecture is obviously $\Pi^0_2$, though I suspect there is some non-obvious way to bring that down to $\Pi^0_1$. The $\mathsf{P}$ vs $\mathsf{NP}$ problem also sits naturally in $\Pi^0_2$, I think.
This question suggests that the placement of the Hodge conjecture is not so obvious.
A theorem, of course, is $\Delta^0_0$, but the "natural" formulation can be considered, e.g. infinitude of primes is $\Pi^0_2$ ("for all numbers $n$, there exists some $p > n$..."). Termination of all Goodstein sequences is naturally $\Pi^0_2$ as well.
This question is the classic "find examples with $n>3$". Of course we know that $\Pi^0_{n+1}$ contains problems strictly harder than $\Pi^0_n$, but it's rare to see examples of such problems, probably because we poor humans can visualize lower levels much more easily, and so are more drawn to them. To prove such theorems, though, we often have to go up in the hierarchy, and so there should be some interesting examples of theorems and definitions up there.
Ramsey theorems ostensibly have very high quantifier alternation, though sadly those quantifications are often bounded, so I fail to see an example with "natural" complexity greater than $\Pi^0_2$.
It's possible somewhat awkwardly encode problems in analysis into arithmetic, which would provide pretty natural problems higher up the ladder, though I'd much prefer to hear about "finitary" problems in combinatorics or number theory.
So to summarize: what are examples of natural finitary conjectures or theorems with "natural logical complexity" at or above $\Pi^0_3$?

See also: https://mathoverflow.net/q/281894/1946

Cody, is your question a duplicate of that question, and if not, what is distinguishing for you?

@JoelDavidHamkins I didn't find that question despite a cursory google and search, dang! It basically asks the same question I am, though one possible difference is that it counts bounded quantifiers as "legitimate", whereas the place in the arithmetic hierarchy would typically be much lower without doing any non-trivial work. E.g. your tic-tac-toe example is $\Delta_0$. Still, maybe I should close this one as duplicate.

Yes, probably best.

Since you also say "To prove such theorems, though, we often have to go up in the hierarchy", are you also accepting answers giving theorems of low quantifier complexity whose proofs necessarily involve formulas of high quantifier complexity? If so (and perhaps editing the question to make this question explicit), this may be one difference from the other question.

I guess, but I'd much rather like to see statements of high complexity that make sense on their own, whereas I'm suspecting that you're thinking about theoretical results in proof theory where you know such statements must exist, but they're not very interesting on their own.

I think it's best that this question is closed, but I'd encourage anyone stumbling upon it with a good answer to go to the other one and add an answer! It is a little on the poor side for now (as a big-list).
